# An image and text query

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a very simple html page here:

http://www.nomorepasting.com/getpaste.php?pasteid=22407

And I have 4 layers on the page. The reason for this is it is the framework oif a much more complicated site, I have simplified it to ask my question. Basically, I want to be able to click on different links in layer 2 and have the image in layer1 change, however The way I have found to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

function sbox(boxName,xname) {

    theBox = document.getElementById(boxName);

theBox.className = xname;



}

//-->

</script>
```

Results in the text nto going away, which I need, as well as a way to click and replace whatever image is there with the text. I found alternative javascript code, but could not apply it to my html page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleImg(myid) {
  objtxt = document.getElementById(myid);
  objimg = document.getElementById(myid+'_img');

  if( objtxt.style.display == 'block' ) { // Show image, hide text
    objtxt.style.display = 'none';
    objimg.style.display = 'block';
  } else { // Hide image, show text
    objimg.style.display = 'none';
    objtxt.style.display = 'block';
  }

}
</script>
```

What is the easiest way to do this without changing the design of my page? note: I do not want to use a framework, I want to understand how this is done and do it for myself.

My additional question is on if layers should replace tables: Is it always bad to use tables when css could be used instead? Is it easy to use layers to make row and column equivalents just to format text data, not the structure of a site?

Comment: Double spacing sucks in questions, we could have really done without it here.

Comment: Consider posting the code as a sample page somewhere else with a link, and the relevant snippet here. You'll probably get more people willing to have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(In response to Joshxtothe4's comment... I needed more space to respond)

Changing the class back to class1 will not show the text again, unfortunately.  The code I gave will hide the text, always, if it's found in a span.  You could do something like below, and add another CSS statement that will hide the span if class4 is used. Then you don't have to have that code in javascript. Probably a cleaner solution:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
                .class1{color:#000;}
                .class2{color:#00f;}
                .class3{color:#0f0;}
                .class4{color:#f00; background-image:url('someimage.jpg');}
        .class4 span { display: none;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                function sbox(divid, classname)
                {
                        document.getElementById(divid).className=classname;
                 }
        </script>
        <div>
        <a href="#" onclick="sbox('div1','class1');return false;">Reset</a><br/>
                <a href="#" onclick="sbox('div1','class2');return false;">Test Div1, Class2(blue)</a><br/>
                <a href="#" onclick="sbox('div1','class3'); return false;">Test Div1, Class3(green)</a><br/>
                <a href="#" onclick="sbox('div1','class4');return false;">Test Div1, Class4(red)</a>
        </div>
        <div id="div1" class="class1"><span id="div1_text">Blah blah blah</span></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As far as having the image as a background, that's probably your best bet. The only problem was that setting background images doesn't hide foreground text. You'd always have to hide that text somehow

Comment: Thankyou so much for your replies! I am still trying to understand it though. How would I add a statement to hide the text if class 4 is used, or indeed any class with a background image?

Comment: The CSS style .class4 span{display:none;} hides the inner text inside the span if class4 is used. Hiding the text if a background image is used, is a much more difficult solution, and I don't have an answer to that at this moment. But, I imagine it would be a javascript solution.

Comment: In theory, could I just have many classes with a background image and a class4 without a background image, would that not work perfectly?

Comment: I guess I don't follow what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Tables are for tabular data (think Excel).  If you have a grid of data to display use a table.  When it comes to page lyouts, use CSS positioning.

Also, obsessive DIV use isn't the best way to use CSS.  Getting into the habit of wrapping everything up in a DIV is a practice known as "div mania" and you can Google for reasons why it's not good.

Comment: What do you mean by div mania? Is it not useful to have a main div to be able to contain everything?

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, when setting a background image, it won't hide the text within the DIV, no matter how high you set the Z-Index. It just doesn't work.  One solution could be to wrap the inner text in a span, and hide the span when you want the background image of the div to show. But, from your question, you didn't want to change your html structure that much, yet, you'll have to in order to get what you want, I believe.

Sample code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .class1{color:#000;}
            .class2{color:#00f;}
            .class3{color:#0f0;}
            .class4{color:#f00; background-image:url('someimage.jpg');}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function sbox(divid, classname)
            {
                document.getElementById(divid).className=classname;
                if(document.getElementById(divid+"_text")!=null)
                    document.getElementById(divid+"_text").style.display="none";
            }
        </script>
        <div>
            <a href="#" onclick="sbox('div1','class2');return false;">Test Div1, Class2(blue)</a><br/>
            <a href="#" onclick="sbox('div1','class3'); return false;">Test Div1, Class3(green)</a><br/>
            <a href="#" onclick="sbox('div1','class4');return false;">Test Div1, Class4(red)</a>
        </div>
        <div id="div1" class="class1"><span id="div1_text">Blah blah blah</span></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I agree with TravisO, HTML tables should be used for tabular data, and not as a layout mechanism. There are also some CSS oddities with tables when you've got a large hierarchy of tables/rows/etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would I just change the class back to 1 to get the text back, and still rely on background images for the other classes to show them? I apologize if I an not understanding correctly. What would be a better way instead of having the image as a background?